# From where i can download the imamat class and how can i use this package in my tex file?

Tags: pdftex

I am writing manuscript paper for IMA journal of Applied Mathematics in its template, which has the code

```
\documentclass{imamat}
```

When I run this for pdftexify then its giving the error message

```
! LaTeX Error: File `imamat.cls' not found.
```

Please  tell me how to include this class file and from where??

Comment: Please have a look on: http://www.oxfordjournals.org/our_journals/imamat/for_authors/imamat_class%20file_2012.zip

Comment: Please tell me in detail . I am not able to find the solution to this problem in the above said link.

Comment: The class file is in there as well as a *HowTo*

Comment: but i am not able to find the the proper file which i have to copy in the directory. And not able to find the directory where i should paste that file. I am new to latex

Answer (score 2):

A fast workaround is in such a case to create a new directory, let's say `test` and then copy all files included in the `zip` file into this directory `test`.

If you have no problems with your TeX distribution you are now able to compile the included file `Author_tex.tex`. Test first, if you can compile from your terminal/console: go to directory `test`, then type `pdflatex Author_tex.tex` and press enter.  Now the compile run starts and creates some files, one of them the file `Author_tex.log`.  There you should find no errors ...

If that was okay, start your editor and try to compile `Author_tex.tex` with the editor.  If the installation and configuration is okay, this compile run should give the same result you got before from the command line/terminal.

If you want to write more than one document with this class I suggest you to create an `localtexmf`. How to do that depends on your used operating system and the used TeX distribution.  Please search on this page for a solution for you (you didn't tell us more informations about your system).